# "first time here?" message with django

Tags: django

Im writing an app that will display the register view depending if is first time visitor.

What and How is the better way to do this with Django?

thxs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use sessions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/

And then do something like:

```
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.session.get('visited', False):
        # response without the welcome message
    else:
        request.session['visited'] = True
        # response with the welcome message
```

For session-related settings (e.g. expiration), see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions

Comment: hi rz, which is the expiration date for this session?

Comment: The links appear to be broken

Comment: The links have been fixed.